# What happens when assigned COM port is 256?

Tags: serial-port, limits

When I connect a new device in the usb, simulating port COM, the number of the COM port increase. What happens when the COM port arrives to 256? I suppose the system goes to the beginning to select the first available COM port, isn´t it?  (Obviously, I´m not using all the COM port at the same time)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would the OS do that? That's the driver's job. The OS simply has some limited resources, and will not give you something it doesn't have.

Comment: The driver takes directly the COM Port? I suppose the OS show the num Port that have free, but if you put a new device the device take COM port incrementally, and maybe other smaller number could be free. My question is what happen when the driver take the last possible port and i would like to connect a new device, It starts again from the first free or I need to clean some register?

Comment: That depends on the driver that handles your USB device. It might even be configurable. Different USB-to-COM devices can have different behaviour. Check with your device's manufacturer. The question is, why do you care? What's your problem?

Comment: There is no relevance to the number, you are not using MS-Dos anymore.  It is just a name, it can't come up with a better one for simulated hardware from the stone age that doesn't support plug & play.  The odds that you'll trigger a bug in the USB device driver are however not zero, they are generally rather poor quality.  Or tax the limit of USB, it can't have more than 127 devices on a controller.

Comment: I´m doing repetitive test in devices. I connect one device I pass a test, I connect the next device I pass the test....

Comment: I could connect a lot of devices, and the driver assign me an incremental COM port for each device. I´m worry about what will happen when arrive to the last possible port assignement.